# Insert certain weekday within a week if it doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name;

CREATE TABLE table_name 
(symbol CHAR(4)
,time DATE 
,bid DECIMAL (7,2)
,ask DECIMAL (7,2)
,PRIMARY KEY(symbol,time)
);

insert into table_name 
(symbol,`time`,bid,ask)
 values 
 ('CN50','2020-09-25',15077.5, 15087.5),
 ('CN50','2020-09-28',15255  , 15265  ),
 ('CN50','2020-09-29',15257  , 15267  ),
 ('CN50','2020-09-30',15258  , 15268  ),
 ('CN50','2020-10-01',15259  , 15269  );

SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(time,'%a') dow FROM table_name;
 +--------+------------+----------+----------+------+
 | symbol | time       | bid      | ask      | dow  |
 +--------+------------+----------+----------+------+
 | CN50   | 2020-09-25 | 15077.50 | 15087.50 | Fri  |
 | CN50   | 2020-09-28 | 15255.00 | 15265.00 | Mon  |
 | CN50   | 2020-09-29 | 15257.00 | 15267.00 | Tue  |
 | CN50   | 2020-09-30 | 15258.00 | 15268.00 | Wed  |
 | CN50   | 2020-10-01 | 15259.00 | 15269.00 | Thu  |
 +--------+------------+----------+----------+------+
```

What I wish to achieve is that if there is no value for Sunday within a week, insert a new row between this Friday and next Monday with Sunday date in time column and copy the bid/ask values from Friday.

In this example, 2020-09-25 is Friday and 2020-09-28 is Monday, I would expect to insert a row with 2020-09-27 as `time` and keep the `bid` and `ask` value from last Friday which is 2020-09-25.

Before:

| Symbol | time | bid | ask |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CN50 | 2020-09-25 | 15077.5 | 15087.5 |
| CN50 | 2020-09-28 | 15255 | 15265 |

After:

| Symbol | time | bid | ask |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CN50 | 2020-09-25 | 15077.5 | 15087.5 |
| CN50 | 2020-09-27 | 15077.5 | 15087.5 |
| CN50 | 2020-09-28 | 15255 | 15265 |

Comment: @Strawberry Hi thanks for the heads, have edited the question. Let me know if it still confuses.

Comment: I would consider this to be a display issue, best resolved in application code.

Comment: @Strawberry Noted with thanks. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, I would handle this kind of thing in application code, but if you know that Friday's going to be there (and, crucially, that Sunday isn't!) , then something like this would suffice...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table_name
 UNION
SELECT symbol
     , time + INTERVAL 2 DAY
     , bid
     , ask 
  FROM table_name 
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(time + INTERVAL 2 DAY,'%a') = 'sun' 
 ORDER 
    BY symbol
     , time;
+--------+------------+----------+----------+
| symbol | time       | bid      | ask      |
+--------+------------+----------+----------+
| CN50   | 2020-09-25 | 15077.50 | 15087.50 |
| CN50   | 2020-09-27 | 15077.50 | 15087.50 |
| CN50   | 2020-09-28 | 15255.00 | 15265.00 |
| CN50   | 2020-09-29 | 15257.00 | 15267.00 |
| CN50   | 2020-09-30 | 15258.00 | 15268.00 |
| CN50   | 2020-10-01 | 15259.00 | 15269.00 |
+--------+------------+----------+----------+
```

If there's a chance that Sunday could be there already, then you could left join this result onto the original data set, and use COALESCE to filter the correct value - but by this point you'd probably want switch back to application code or employ the CTE/Windowing tools available in MySQL 8.0+

Comment: There is a chance that Sunday is there which would lead to duplicate dates with the later one being correct(the one that is different with Friday value). Since I have specified unique constraint for symbol and time, so what I did based on your answer is to insert ignore the selected results into the original data set, that should do the trick.